# How do I pass variables through Facebook App Install Ad URL?

Tags: facebook, ads

I'm trying to pass Apple's campaign & affiliate codes through the Facebook App Install ad, however, I don't see a place in FB to do it.

When I view the Install Now link, the URL ends with the app ID number - and I'd like it to have a ?at=xxxxxx in there.

Anyone know how to do this for Mobile Install Ads?

Comment: Where this url redirects your users?

Comment: The URL takes users to the App Store.